# Spring get system.property in application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I have created a Spring Boot application and set a Systemproperty with a gradle task:

```
System.setProperty("rootPath", "${projectDir}")
```

now I would like to get the property (System.getProperty("rootPath") in the application.properties (Spring).

```
propery.path.supplier = ${rootPath}/directory/example
```

However, I don't get the value, does anyone know a solution? Thanks.

Comment: How are you referring to your property in your Java code ?

Is it a typo ? You've written propery rather than property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `systemProperty(name,value)` method in your build.gradle instead of System.setProperty

```
yourTask {
  systemProperty "rootPath", projectDir
}
```